# Group is created to the right of Parent

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to add a sub group to a parent group but to have that sub group sit below the parent group row.  Right now if I right click the parent group and add a child group..it adds a child group but to the RIGHT of the first parent group's cell in the report.

Anyone??  How the heck do you get child groups to sit below the parent row?

For example my report will have a parent group that holds a CarType
For each Car Type group, it has several related car names

```
------------------------------------------------
Honda
Field1   3   4   54  534
Field2   5   3   44  455
------------------------------------------------
Accord
Field1   53  3   43  222
Field2   5  22   24  423

Pilot
Field1   4  3    5   221
Field2   5  27   24  423

..... rest of the car types for honda


------------------------------------------------
Toyota
Field1   3   4   54  534
Field2   5   3   44  455
------------------------------------------------
Camry
Field1   53  3   43  222
Field2   5  22   24  423

xxxx
Field1   4  3    5   221
Field2   5  27   24  423

..... rest of the car types for camry
```

and so on.  So we don't want the children to be indented (I'm not sure if this is now not going to be stepped or what..that's what I'm having trouble with cause every example out there on the net shows you how to do a stepped report but shows the the child group indented in a little which we don't want for x business reasons.

I can't get this parent/child set of rows to look like this in the report.  I want nested (parent/child) but child should be starting flush left, not indented in relation to the parent when viewing the data.

Here is an example in another report and you can see the groups stacked:

[image]

another example in another report

[image]

Comment: I still do not get why when I right click a cell and choose to create a group does it add a whole new column to either the right or left of the call you clicked on. I want the group to be created RIGHT WHERE RIGHT CLICKED..THE CELL THAT I RIGHT CLICKED ON TO CREATE THIS GROUP.

Answer (score 4):

There's probably more than one way to do this, but I'll explain this way to keep it easy to follow.

1. Start with a table, and add your child group to the first column in the details row.
2. Right-click that cell with your child group, point to Add Group, and then click Parent Group in the Row Group section.
3. In the Group By drop-down list, select the parent group and select the Add group header check box, and click OK. Another column gets added to the left of your detail group and the Row Groups pane now shows the parent group and child group. A new row appears between the table header and the child row (details row)
4. Delete the new column.
5. Add the parent field to the first column in the row above the details row.

Comment: holy crap...that's not very intuitive MS.  Thanks Stacia I'll give that  a try.

Comment: what do you mean by "Right-click that cell with your child group".  With your child group?  I don't get what you mean by with.... and I can't add a child group in Step 1, only a parent initially.

Comment: I'm able to do what you say but when I try to add a child group, I'm getting the same issues, how to stack it

Comment: also how do you create a table with more than 3 columns?  I tried to select a bunch of cells going across but it doesn't paint a table with that many columns when it creates the table

Comment: I still do not get why when I right click a cell and choose to create a group does it add a whole new column to either the right or left of the call you clicked on.  I want the group to be created RIGHT WHERE RIGHT CLICKED..THE CELL THAT I RIGHT CLICKED ON TO CREATE THIS GROUP.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I didn't mean literally to add a child group in step 1. I was using your terminology. I'm going to assume that Car Type is the parent group and that Car is the child group. In Step 1, you need to add a table to the report and add Car to the first column in the details row. Then in step 2, you add a parent group (the Car Type). It's going to create another column. Get rid of it. Put the Car Type field above the Car field. To add another column, right click on the gray handle and select Insert Column.  This works - I've done it myself many times.

Comment: When you add a row group, it adds a column because that's how a tablix works. You'll see a double-dashed line to the left of your initial column (with Car in it). Every column to the left of that line is a grouping and there are special behaviors you get with that (like spanning cells vertically across child rows). You aren't required to keep it, so delete the column. To the right of the double-dashed line is the body - other types of behavior for that. I have much more explanation for it in my next book but I can't explain it all here!

Comment: Stacia, read your initial answer, was able to insert a group in the middle of a bunch of others and maintain the offset/style formatting with the new functionality. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 3):

Quick, albeit non-intutive, fix for adding a new Parent Group after the tablix has been created:

1. Add the Group in the groups section.
2. A new column to the left will appear and probably mess your beatiful layout. Don't leave that new section just yet.
3. Right-click and insert a new Row.
4. Mark that new row by writing something on it (i.e. "This is Parent 01")
5. Right-click the newly (and undesirable) "left grouping column". Delete it and be careful to just delete the column, NOT the associated group level.
6. Voilà! Now you have a new Parent Group and a place where to put things in it, like a new group title, aggregates or whatever you fancy.

Hope it helps!
If, not drop a line.